# Swift: error passing self as inout parameter parameter

Tags: swift

I have this case:

```
class classA{
  var objB : classB;

   init(){
      objB = classB(&self) //ERROR!
  }
}

class classB{
 var _objA : classA

  init(inout objA : classA){
      _objA = objA;
  }
}
```

I receive the message: 'classA' is not a subtype of '@lvalue $T3'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is misleading, but your program should not compile: it does not make sense to pass `self` as an in-out parameter. Swift book is clear about what can be passed as `inout`:

> You can only pass a variable as the argument for an in-out parameter.

This makes perfect sense: imagine what would happen if your function assigned a new value to its `objA` parameter. Since it corresponds to `self` in the caller, the caller object would need to be replaced with a new one, which does not have a clear semantics.

You can fix this by defining a temporary variable for `self`, like this:

```
var temp = self;
objB = classB(&temp)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the operation you described doesn't have a clear systematic.

Comment: @user3903647 Think about what should happen when `init` assigns something to `objA`, which is bound to `self`: this would mean that all variables that reference the old `self` must be re-pointed to the replacement object. Once you consider that some of the references may be from constant objects, this semantic becomes impossible. Did you try this with a local `temp` variable?

Comment: While this makes perfect sense, how would one go about to send an object to be configured? For instance, I want to send my object to an "injector" class to have it's dependencies injected, based on protocols it complies to. The pattern I used in Objective C was to have the init method call the Injector for self, and then the Injector would call setters for the missing dependencies. How can I do this in SWIFT?

Comment: @Fervus You may want to ask this as a separate question.